# AngularJS directives talk to controller to call a function onchange

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive that looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    {{templateMapping[colProp].SheetPointer}}
    <select class="form-control"
        ng-model="selectedColumn"
        ng-change="changeMapping()"
        ng-options="Col.SheetPointer for Col in optionList"></select>
</div>
```

Note the `ng-change`.

My directive code looks like the following:

```
angular
.module('app.import')
.directive('mappingEdit', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "partials/templates/MappingEdit.html",
        scope: {
            templateMapping: "=", //parent object
            colProp: "@", //name of property
            optionList: "=",
            colFilter: "=filter"
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.selectedColumn = {};
            scope.changeMapping = function() {
                // ng-change fired here!
                scope.templateMapping[scope.colProp] = scope.selectedColumn;
                // call "autoSave here, commitSave is in the Controller...
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

The custom directive is used like so:

```
<mapping-edit 
    template-mapping="mapping" 
    col-prop="MappedColumn" 
    option-list="columnList" 
    filter="selectedSheet.SheetName" />
```

As you can see, my directive html code is a `<select>` and has an `ng-change` I want to call a function in my controller that is called `commitSave` and it looks like the following:

```
$scope.commitSave = function () {
    alert("on changed!")
}
```

How can I call this controller function from my directive with `ng-change`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this two ways.

1. You can pass the function in the scope definition such as:

   ```
       scope: {
           templateMapping: "=", //parent object
           colProp: "@", //name of property
           optionList: "=",
           colFilter: "=filter"
           updateFn: "&"
       },
   ```

   and in the markup:

   ```
   <mapping-edit 
   template-mapping="mapping" 
   col-prop="MappedColumn" 
   option-list="columnList" 
   filter="selectedSheet.SheetName" 
   updateFn="commitSave"/>
   ```

   and finally, in your link function:

   ```
   scope.changeMapping = function() {
           // ng-change fired here!
           scope.templateMapping[scope.colProp] = scope.selectedColumn;
           scope.updateFn()
       };
   ```
2. Use events :)

Here is a plunker from the angular docs, demonstrating.
http://plnkr.co/edit/UTPVE1qeTraJZcWRK1UO?p=info

Comment: Events are bad! I don't recommend to use that without any specific reasons

Comment: `updateFn="commitSave"` good, but is not best! Would be better to use AngularJS style like `updateFn="commitSave(param1, param2)"`

Comment: The commitSave in your example is fired in the directive, I need to fire a function in the controller. The reason being is that the commitSave will have extra data that is available only in the controller.

Comment: Excuse me, but how are events "bad" exactly? Also his commit save function has no parameters, and the markup here is specifying what to import from the parent scope, not invoking the function >.>

Comment: @JeffC the '&' tells this to evaluate the expression in the parent scope, so it will be firing your controller method, I have also added the parens

Comment: @lucky7id Events (I'm talking about custom user events) are bad because it is complex to debug, it uglies readability, also in long perspective it is low-performance technique if you is going to use it a lot.

Comment: @lucky7id I see what you did here, makes complete sense. I did this sort of thing earlier in my code too, I thought I was doing it wrong because my function in the controller is never fired! hmmm

Comment: @Max Except for the fact that events are non-blocking, and declarative. I am not sure how the isolate scope API is somehow more readable than a simple `$scope.emit` in your eyes, but oh well. Side-note, react and backbone are built on events, angular is the exception here.

Comment: This was the right answer. Just one thing I'd like to add `updateFn="commitSave()"` should be `update-fn="commitSave"` otherwise it will never work

Comment: I had put 'commitSave' initially, but a quick browse on the docs to double check, they had it with the invocation, might depend on the version though, or perhaps it was a wrapper function. I'll revert the change

Answer (score -2):

Can add another attribute to pass the controller function into the directive scope

```
<mapping-edit 
    template-mapping="mapping" 
    col-prop="MappedColumn" 
    option-list="columnList"
    commit-save ="commitSave" 
    filter="selectedSheet.SheetName" />
```

JS

```
angular
.module('app.import')
.directive('mappingEdit', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "partials/templates/MappingEdit.html",
        scope: {
            templateMapping: "=", //parent object
            colProp: "@", //name of property
            optionList: "=",
            colFilter: "=filter",
            commitSave : '=' // bind to controller function
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.selectedColumn = {};
            scope.changeMapping = function() {
                // ng-change fired here!
                scope.templateMapping[scope.colProp] = scope.selectedColumn;
                // call "autoSave 
                scope.commitSave( /* params */ )

            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Add new AngularJS-like API to your directive called `on-change`:

```
<mapping-edit 
   template-mapping="mapping" 
   col-prop="MappedColumn" 
   option-list="columnList" 
   on-change="commitSave()"
   filter="selectedSheet.SheetName" />
```

Trigger that method inside `changeMapping`:

```
scope.changeMapping = function() {
   // ng-change fired here!
   scope.templateMapping[scope.colProp] = scope.selectedColumn;
   // trigger on-change hook here!
   $parse(attrs.onChange)(scope);
};
```

Don't forget to inject service `$parse`

Comment: I'll give this a go, I didn't know about $parse

Comment: this never called my controller function either, I added a console.log to my commitSave() in my controller and never gets called either... AngularJS can be frustrating at times!

Comment: `alert($parse(attrs.onChange)(scope));` is undefined if I console.log it, but I can `console.log(attrs.onChange)(scope));` and I get `commitSave()` in the console, which is the closest I got so far

Comment: @JeffC if your `commitSave` returns nothing then `$parse(attrs.onChange)(scope)` return nothing as well